# Show that $A^TB=A^TC$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

> If for two suitable matrices $B,C$ ;$AA^TB=AA^TC$ where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix then show that $A^TB=A^TC$.

If $A^TB\neq A^TC$,then $(A^TB- A^TC)(x)\neq 0$
for some  $x\in \Bbb R^m$;

Let  $(A^TB-A^TC)(x)=y\implies A((A^TB-A^TC)(x))=Ay\in Im(A)$.

Also $AA^TB=AA^TC\implies A(A^TB-A^TC)(x)=0\implies (A^TB-A^TC)(x)\in N(A)$.

Hence $ (A^TB-A^TC)(x)\in N(A)\cap Im(A^T)=\{0\}\implies A^TB=A^TC$.

[Since $N(A)\cap Im(A^T)=\{0\}$].

Is my solution correct?Please suggest edits if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really. You take an arbitrary $x$ and set $(A^TB - A^C)(x) = y$ and you want to show that $y = 0$. Then you say that $Ay \in \operatorname{Im}(A)$ and also $Ay = 0$ so $y \in \ker(A)$ but you haven't shown that $y \in \operatorname{Im}(A)$ which is what you claim. Even if you do, there's no reason that $\ker(A) \cap \operatorname{Im}(A) = \{ 0 \}$.

Let's start over. You are given that $AA^TD = 0$ and you want to show that $A^T D = 0$ (your result is obtained by taking $D = B - C$). By the assumption, we have $\operatorname{Im}(A^TD) \subseteq \ker(A)$ but since $\ker(A) = \operatorname{im}(A^T)^{\perp}$, we also have

$$\operatorname{Im}(A^TD) \subseteq \operatorname{Im}(A^T) \cap \operatorname{Im}(A^T)^{\perp} = \{ 0 \} $$

and so $A^TD = 0$.

Comment: Thank you;One point I am preparing for an exam where questions of this kind are asked;Can you tell me which books to use for that?How to prepare for that

Comment: @Maths_Student: Sorry, I don't have anything in mind. You can learn the theory from any decent textbook on linear algebra (Hoffman & Kunze, Axler) and then solve as many exercises as possible. You'll probably enjoy more the book by Axler (Linear Algebra Done Right).

Answer (score 0):

A bit more elementary approach:

1. Show that $N(A^T)=N(AA^T)$ (hint: $AA^Tx$ implies $\|Ax\|_2=0$).
2. Show that $A^TX=0$ iff $AA^TX=0$ by using (1) for each column of $X$.
3. Substitute $X=B-C$.